# Bundles in karaf not able to resolve java libraries

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have java_home set in linux and in bin/karaf script file one entry is:

JAVA_EXT_DIRS="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib:${KARAF_HOME}/lib/ext"

When my karaf is up and running and a flow is tested below error is throw:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError not found..

But this should be provided by rt.jar and rt.jar is present in "${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib" hence I added same section in JAVA_EXT_DIRS entry.
But same error persists.

I should get java libraries from karaf. 
Help me understanding the cause.

Comment: FYI... issue is fixed. The solution is to modify the below line in karaf script or karaf.bat 
JAVA_EXT_DIRS="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext:${KARAF_HOME}/lib/ext" and added ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib.

Answer (score 2):

Your bundle needs to import the package `javax.xml.transform` in its Import-Package statement.

In general you need to import all packages that you actually use, with the sole exception of packages beginning with `java.`, which includes for example `java.lang`, `java.util` etc but not `javax.*`.

Comment: It is present in Import-Package section.

Comment: @technicalworm ... of the correct bundle? I.e. the one that actually needs it? You will need to show more information to proceed further.

Comment: FYI... issue is fixed. The solution is to modify the below line in karaf script or karaf.bat JAVA_EXT_DIRS="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext‌​:${KARAF_HOME}/lib/e‌​xt" and added ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib.